# What is benefit in resolvers angular 5

Tags: angular

I'm a newbee in Angular 2+ . Some people use **Resolver** between http service getting data and a component.

```
export class UserResolver implements Resolve<User> {

constructor(
    private service: UserService,
    private router: Router
) {}

resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
): Observable<User> {
    const id = route.paramMap.get('id');
    return this.service.getUser(+id)
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err); // deal with API error (eg not found)
            this.router.navigate(['/']); // could redirect to error page
            return Observable.empty<User>();
        });
}
```

}

Questions are:

1. What is **practical benefit** of that? (i see only redundant class as a bridge on each invocation)

   2. Is this recommended way and if should refactor existing code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to Jim Cooper Pluralsight course:
https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=angular-fundamentals&author=jim-cooper&name=angular-fundamentals-m5&clip=8&mode=live

1. In case of first approach without Resolver we need to wait until data is loaded via  asyncronous subscribe. In component some elements are displayed immediately and some after Observable.subscribe call.
2. In second case resolver catches all data and passed it to the component
   Data in component is not shown up until all component is loaded.

So resolver helps to cook data before component is shown.

Comment: Can ugly workaround to this be using *ngIf="data" on the entire component's template. So it's not shown till the data is received from service?

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at this introduction to [Angular Resolvers](https://codeburst.io/understanding-resolvers-in-angular-736e9db71267).
Looking at the steps below, notice that in step 2 your example is returning an Observable.

Quoting from the article:

**So basically resolver is that intermediate code, which can be executed when a link has been clicked and before a component is loaded.**

... here is the high level approach:

**General Routing Flow**

1. User clicks the link.
2. Angular loads the respective component.

**Routing Flow with Resolver**

1. User clicks the link.
2. Angular executes certain code and returns a value or observable.
3. You can collect the returned value or observable in constructor or in ngOnInit, in class of your component which is about to load.
4. Use the collected the data for your purpose.
5. Now you can load your component.

Steps 2,3 and 4 are done with a code called Resolver.

Comment: Todd, i don't realize practice usage. The purpose is to collect data before onInit?

Comment: Yes, a Resolver is very useful when you need to fetch data from an asynchronous service before you display the component from a route. And yes, it runs before ngOnInit so you can fetch the data first.